# Why do I keep getting 'undefined method' when it's worked fine before?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

My OrdersController is as follows below, but I keep getting this message:

undefined method `listing_id=' for #

Extracted source (around line #31):
        29
        30
        31    @order.listing_id = @listing.id

Is there something I am doing incorrectly?  Am following a tutorial so followed the instructions, then when it wasn't working decided to copy and paste, and it's still not working.  Please, any help is appreciated.

Full code is as follows

```
    class OrdersController < ApplicationController
       before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!

 def sales
@orders = Order.all.where(seller: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
end

def purchases
@orders = Order.all.where(buyer: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
   end

   # GET /orders/new
     def new
       @order = Order.new
       @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
     end



  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json

def create
@order = Order.new(order_params)
@listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
@seller = @listing.user


@order.listing_id = @listing.id
@order.buyer_id = current_user.id
@order.seller_id = @seller.id

 Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
token = params[:stripeToken]

begin
  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount => (@listing.price * 100).floor,
    :currency => "usd",
    :card => token
    )
  flash[:notice] = "Thanks for ordering!"
rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:danger] = e.message
end

respond_to do |format|
  if @order.save
    format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_order
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:address, :city, :state)
end
    end
```

Comment: Is your database fully migrated?

Comment: No it wasn't fully migrated.  had to run 'rails generate' then rake:db migrate for  listings_id.  Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Fields of the Order Model. Do you have listing_id as a column on the orders table ? Check the migration files to make sure that somewhere along the way you have added a "listing_id" field to the "orders" table.

Comment: thank you, this was this issue.  I ran rake db:migrate with listings_id

Answer (score 0):

Define strong params:

```
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:address, :city, :state, :listing_id, :buyer_id, :seller_id  )
end
```